# How to do a jQuery selection starting from a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In Vanilla JavaScript, one way to select an element from the DOM is:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('[css selector]');
```

You can then use this element to select elements within this element, which can be done like this:

```js
element.querySelector('[other css selector]');
```

I tried looking it up on jQuery's documentation, but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to do this in jQuery? Maybe something like:

```js
let element = $('[css selector]');
element.select('[other css selector]');

// or maybe
$(element, '[other css selector]');
```

I know I can do this:

```js
element[0].querySelector('[other css selector]');
```

But that is converting it back into a native element and then using the native JavaScript method. Is there a way to do this with only jQuery methods?

Comment: RTD: https://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, awesome! Thank you. I tried searching for it, but didn't really know what to search for.

Comment: The "or may be" part in your question is actually somewhat correct: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

Comment: @SalmanA, so I was partially correct, I just had it switched... thank you for your input.

Comment: If either of you (@RoryMcCrossan or @SalmanA) want to put your comments as answers, I will mark it as the answer (Favoring Rory's answer more, since that is the closest to what I was looking for, but both are good especially for others who have the same question as I did). Thank you, both, again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can achieve identical behavior using [`jQuery.find(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector) method:

```
let $element = $('#some-div');
let $someGrandChildren = $element.find('b, i, u');
```

A less common approach is to use [`jQuery(selector[, context ])`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) method where the context argument could be a DOM Element, Document, jQuery or selector. So this works as expected too:

```
let $element = $('#some-div');
let $someGrandChildren = $('b, i, u', $element);
```

According to the documentation, this method uses `.find()` behind the scene.

Comment: Thank you for adding this, and including both things from the comments. This will help others who come looking for answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#thefirstselector .yoursecond .yourthird #fourth');
```

Comment: I want it specifically to be done from an object I already have. That would work as long as I had the selector each time. Sometimes I am using objects that have been passed into a function or by some other way. Thank you for your input though.